# How to decouple swagger code and application code in node nest js framework

Tags: nestjs

I just have gone through the swagger integration with nest js framework. it was awesome but it looks like my code is integrated with the swagger specific code so even in production compiled code it will be present. I don't like to move my documentation specific code to production code also I'm thinking whether it will impact any performance. Is there a way to decouple the things.

@j_steenkamp_twitter responded: I don't think Swagger will have a large footprint and will impact your application performance. Secondly, putting your Swagger documentation in production will trigger you to spend that extra time on making your application secure